# Como cambiar el color de letra con canvas

Tags: canvas

Dibujo una cadena en las coordenadas X,Y

```
pdf.drawString(230, 780, u"Contrato de CubanCloud")
```

Ahora quiero que en lugar de salir esa cadena en negro, quiero que salga azul, por favor diganme como puedo hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Qué es `drawString`? ¿Qué estás usando para escribir en el canvas?
 ¿Estás usando Syncfusion o ReportLab o algo así?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por el código que compartes, parece que estás generando un PDF usando canvas en ReportLab. Entonces para cambiar el color, lo primero que deberías hacer es definir qué color quieres usar con el método `setFillColor` antes de llamar a `drawString`.

Por ejemplo, si quieres que sea azul en lugar de negro, harías algo como esto:

```
pdf.setFillColor(blue)
pdf.drawString(230, 780, u"Contrato de CubanCloud")
```

También podrías usar `setFillColorRGB` para indicar el color en modo RGB pasando 3 parámetros. Puedes encontrar más información en la [documentación de ReportLabs sobre colores](https://www.reportlab.com/documentation/faq/#2.1.4) (en inglés).

Answer (score 1):

En JavaScript basico se hace asi:

```js
var papel = document.getElementById("papel");
var lapiz = papel.getContext("2d");

lapiz.font = '30px Verdana';
lapiz.fillStyle = 'blue';
lapiz.fillText('Esto es azul', 10, 40);

lapiz.fillStyle = 'red';
lapiz.fillText('Esto es rojo', 20, 80);

lapiz.fillStyle = 'yellow';
lapiz.strokeStyle = "black";
lapiz.fillText('Esto es amarillo con borde negro', 10, 120);
lapiz.strokeText('Esto es amarillo con borde negro', 10, 120);
```

```html
<canvas id="papel" width="600" height="200">
</canvas>
```